# Finding likelihood of distribution of events across categories

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood

Things I have :

Categories: `[A, B, C,....., Z, A1, B1, C1......., Z5]`

Likelihood of co-occurence of 2 categories :

```
{  
   A-B : 0.14,                                            
   A-C : 0.09,                                            
   A-D : 0.34,                                           
       .                                            
       .                                          
       .                                              
       .                                              
  Y5-Z5: 0.01                                                   
}
```

Event-counts distribution across categories :

```
1.    {A: 34, B: 23, F3: 56}                                          
2.    {B2: 13, Z4: 41, K: 78, L:77}
3.    {V1: 3, H5: 38, R: 66, J:22}
4.    {A:22, B:33}
5.    {A:22, C:33}
```

And I want to find out the likelihood of each of the above event-count distribution.

Expectation from statistics solution:

It should differentiate in the 4th and 5th items above. As `A` category is more likely with `B` as compared to `C`, 4th should get a better likelihood score than 5th.

If the algorithm can also take into account the count of events instead of just the mere co-occurrence in 2 categories, it is a bonus for us.

The example of 4th and 5th just takes into account a single pair, but in reality, the number of categories can be much more with the total number of pairs  being `nC2`

Comment: By categories you mean just classes? Is A1 special case of A? Maybe you could try to distill your answer, i.e. remove details (keep simple notation), but leave the point.

Comment: @hans A1 is NOT a special case A. Yes, categories mean only classes.